# Match on child discriminated union

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

If I have a discriminated union with multiple values sharing a child (`Apple` and `MoreApples` both have type `Apple`)...

```
type Apples =
  | GrannySmith
  | Gala

type Fruit =
  | Apple of Apples
  | MoreApples of Apples
  | Banana

let speakFruit = function
  | Apple GrannySmith 
  | MoreApples GrannySmith -> "granny smith"
  | Apple Gala 
  | MoreApples Gala -> "gala"
  | Banana -> "banana"
```

Is there a way to match on the sub-union to remove duplication? - something like:

```
let speakFruit2 = function
  | _ GrannySmith -> "granny smith"
  | _ Gala -> "gala"
  | Banana -> "banana"
```

Comment: Are you in full control of your types or are they 3rd party? If the former then maybe do something like [this](https://ideone.com/Slqg4F) instead?

Comment: There is no way to do this, and this is actually a sign that your types do not reflect your domain well enough.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a nice way to do this with single pattern, but you can define an active pattern that will give you an alternative perspective of the data where the two kinds of apples are merged:

```
let (|AnyApple|Banana|) = function
  | Apple a | MoreApples a -> AnyApple a
  | Banana -> Banana
```

This hides the standard `Banana` definition - you should probably use another name to avoid confusion, but the rest stays the same. Now you can pattern match using `AnyApple`:

```
let speakFruit = function
  | AnyApple GrannySmith -> "granny smith"
  | AnyApple Gala -> "gala"
  | Banana -> "banana"
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
let speakFruit = function
| Apple x | MoreApples x -> 
    match x with
    | GrannySmith -> "Granny Smith"
    | Gala -> "gala"
| Banana -> "banana"
```

Answer (score 2):

Partial Active Pattern could also be a solution

```
let (|IsKind|_|) kind z =
    match z with
    | Apple x | MoreApples x -> if (kind = x) then Some true else None
    | _ -> None

let speakFruit x = 
    match x with
    | IsKind GrannySmith z -> "Granny Smith"
    | IsKind Gala z -> "Gala"
    | Banana -> "banana"
    | _ -> "something else"
```

But to be honest - I agree with Fyodor above. You probably should rethink your types.